# Upload video on VK server by link using Python POST

Tags: python, post, video, vk

I am trying to upload video on VK server by link. The only example I found is this:

```
file = {'video_file': ('trailer.avi', open(r'trailer.avi', 'rb'))}
data = {'act': "do_add", "gid": "0", "mid": "201488113", "aid": "-14",
         "hash": "87ed1181ba5b40c260df7914b923be9c",
         "rhash": "1bbf503b59af0a7e384026a74b1887dd", 
         "swfupload": "1", "api": "1", "wallphoto": "1"}
r = r.post(upload_url, data, files=file)
```

Finally, after generating upload link and executing that code I get

> "Responce 200"

But there is no video in the upload directoty. What am I doing wrong there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using the [video.save endpoint](https://vk.com/pages?oid=-17680044&p=video.save)?   If so, the parameters you're passing look way off.  You probably need to consult the documentation.

HTTP response 200 means the request was OK, but in order to tell what's going on you need to inspect the result that the server sends back after this call.  You can again check the documentation for information on that (see link above)

Comment: Thank you! But this is my main problem - the documentation only tells to send POST request on the **upload_url** with field **video_file** contains video to upload. Please, can you give me an advice where to find info about how to execute upload through POST correctly?